# Which HttpStatusCode should I return when a POST method to add an object fails

Tags: asp.net, wcf-web-api

Which HttpStatusCode should I return when a POST method to add an object fails?

It could be due to a db connectivity issue, a code bug, invalid data, or any other reason.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on why it failed. If it failed because the client did something wrong (i.e. tried to POST a duplicate, or tried to POST incorrectly formatted data), then you should use 400 (there are a few special cases where you might use a specific 4xx instead). If it's a bug in your server code (an unexpected exception or an ASSERT failing), then you should use 500. For more information on HTTP status codes and their meanings [read the spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).